# How to add missing Android javadoc to Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc

My Eclipse is missing some Android javadoc options. For instance, I don't get autocomplete option for `android:layout_span`, which is under [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html). How do I add these javadocs and others that may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons for the same
1. You may be using older min SDK version, hence auto complete does not come
2. Javadoc does not popup.

If your jar has a given api, then you will get the autocomplete for sure, autocomplete has got nothing to do with javadoc.

As you have asked about javadoc, let me show you how to set it up.

In your project, you must see Android 4.4 as one of the library dependency, expand it.
you will see android.jar, right click > properties.

There you can see javadoc location as one of the option
Give the javadoc location as http://developer.android.com/reference/

You can validate it as well.

This should give you javadoc. but the problem you are explaining is not a javadoc issue.

Check the projects manifest file to see if the min SDK is proper.